# PHP: do "+=" if exist, "=" if not exist

Tags: php

there is something more efficient than:

```
if(isset($x)){
    $x += 10;
}else{
    $x = 10;
}
```

Consider that my code is more complicated, like:

```
if(isset($complicated_array[$month][$category][$type])){
    $complicated_array[$month][$category][$type] += $value[$month];
}else{
    $complicated_array[$month][$category][$type] = $value[$month];
}
```

i'm searching something like

```
$x = add_smart($x, 10);
```

Comment: Then just implement `add_smart()` function : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Php 7, you can use the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

```
$x = ($x ?? 0) + 10;
```

Comment: This is very interesting.

Comment: This still needs `$complicated_array[$month][$category][$type] = ($complicated_array[$month][$category][$type] ?? 0) + $value[$month];`

Comment: I'm not really seeing a way around writing it at least twice. There's too many operations being performed here: checking if it's set, assigning a default value, summing two values, applying the sum to an array element. That's 4 actions you're trying to stuff into one line. Might be able to make that easier on the eyes by using a pass-by-reference temp variable, but references are best leveraged sparingly. Another alternative might be dot-notation, if you have a converter for that. Thing is though, there's really nothing wrong with manipulating a multi-level array like that in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

About the simplest is

```
function add_smart( &$var, $amount ) {
    $var += $amount;
}
```

this uses a reference, which will set the value if it doesn't exist.

This can then be called using

```
add_smart($complicated_array[$month][$category][$type], 10);
```

Comment: If the `$type` key doesn't exist as you attempt to send that value, I'm pretty sure this would result in an 'Undefined index' error. I _think_ Php can kind of ignore those if you're not in strict mode or a framework that enforces errors, but it's not really a clean solution. I'd watch my error_log if attempting this one.

Comment: @kmuenkel, absolutely not, I run test on CLI with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, if you want to try this and check your error logs I would be happy for your feedback.

Comment: I stand corrected. I see that since $var is by-reference, the $type element gets defined on the spot if it needs to. Would $var default to `null` then, and get type-forced to `0` during the operation then? This is actually kind of a cool solution.

Comment: i think that this make a warning if $complicated_array[$month][$category][$type] is null

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if you set `$complicated_array[$month][$category][$type] = null;` before the function call, it doesn't give any message.

Comment: I cannot set null for each value of month, categoty, type.this is an array for a reason. Because i don't know which value will be filled. Some months may be missing.